# minSdkVersion positive 32-bit integer

Tags: android, android-manifest

I am trying to publish an application in the market and i am getting the following error.

> Market requires the minSdkVersion to be set to a positive 32-bit
>   integer in AndroidManifest.xml.

this is my manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.v3.scribeair.lite" android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk minSdkVersion="6" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/icon">
        <activity android:name=".ScribeAirActivity" android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".DeviceListActivity" android:label="@string/select_device"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" />
        <activity android:name=".AboutActivity" android:label=""
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of this `<uses-sdk minSdkVersion="6" />`

use this one

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="6" />
```

Comment: do i need to again sign the APK after doing this change. and just to understand people using 2.0 android can use the application right ?

Comment: Thanks Surya... will try it and let you know :)